# Replace corrupt system file from windows 7 recovery console

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am having issues booting my windows 7 (service pack 1) laptop and I have been online trying fixes for hours. Based on the evidence it seems I most likely have a corrupt **ntdll.dll** in my system32 folder. One forum I read said to get the file from a computer with the same installation of windows and replace it using the recovery console. I tried this, but I get the message:

> The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a
>   user-mapped section open.

Is there any way I can replace this file?

(All my restore points failed, startup recovery failed, sfc said it fixed corrupt files, but issue persists, and diskcheck said no problems so I am really out of options)

thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell this error is telling me that the file is being used by another process. Is there some way I can stop it?

Comment: You can try to schedule a file replacement operation with SysInternals tools http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx

Comment: Tried it out, cant be run without starting windows. Says "The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present."  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

boot from the Windows 7 DVD go into the [Windows Recovery Environment](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11028.how-to-access-windows-recovery-environment-in-windows-7.aspx) and run the command prompt and run this:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

Replace C: with the drive letter where you installed Windows. Is sfc able to restore the missing or corrupted ntdll.dll?

Comment: When I run the WRE it shows my Windows directory is on E: (although it was on C: when booting up normally)>
is this typical?
And should I use c: or e: in your example?

Comment: @ClayNichols if Windows is E use E:\ in the commandline

Comment: Yep, did that. It at least ran and finished, but SFC was not able to replace some files. Not sure where to get them and they are all in AMD directories and I am on an Intel processor so hoping I don't need those :)

Comment: @ClayNichols AMD created the first x64 CPU (Athlon64), so Microsoft used the codename amd64 for their first 64Bit Windows and still uses this for files. this has nothing to do which CPU you use. Can you share the logs, so that we can see which files are damaged?